# how to debug xslt in umbraco

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I want to debug a xslt used in umbraco (4.0) user control. The xslt is using static .net methods from an assembly say MyAssembly. The `xslExtensions.config` has been setup with the following entry  `<ext assembly="/bin/MyAssembly" type="MyAssembly.Utility" alias="MyAssembly.Utility" />`

This is referenced and used in the xslt file like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:MyAssembly.Utility="urn:MyAssembly.Utility"....
-------------------------------------------------->

--------------------------------------------------
<xsl:variable name="Id" select="MyAssembly.Utility:GetQueryStringValue('tlid')"></xsl:variable>
```

The assembly is copied in the bin folder of the application

The xslt file is quite big and extensively using .net methods. I'm just wondering how can I debug the XSLT by adding breakpoints at various lines. If I run the application just like any .net application and put break points  then these breakpoints don't get a hit. If I use the XSLT debug options from the Visual studio menu i.e. `Start XSLT Debugging`  then the debugging starts but I get the error on this line `<xsl:variable name="Id" select="MyAssembly.Utility:GetQueryStringValue('tlid')"></xsl:variable>`

the error is "Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'urn:MyAssembly.Utility'."

Any ideas how can we debug the xslt as explained in this MS visual studio walk-through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255602.aspx using .net methods?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used XSLT so i'm probably not going to help with what I'm going to say, but since I've been doing this since day 1 why don't you use break points in Visual Studio to see what your code does? That's the only way I've needed so far in debugging my code.